# How to reset the TTS / Spoken Content system in macOS 14 Sonoma when voices will not download/activate?

Tags: siri, text-to-speech, sonoma, voice, speech

I've noted that I cannot download voices in macOS 14 Sonoma any longer and when they "seem" to download, they will not activate or show as having downloaded. I cannot seem to use another or 'new' account to do this either - it seems to behave this way for all user accounts:
[image]

Is there a way to reset the speech subsystem so as to see if this might resolve the problem?